# Ember 2.1 Input Field Overwriting Computed Property

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a computed property that listens to a model and looks something like:

```
groups: function() {
    let g = this.get('model.items.groups').map(function(obj) { return obj.group; });
    return g.join(',');
  }.property('model.items.groups'),
```

In my template, I have the following input field:

```
{{input value=groups type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Testme"}}
```

I noticed that after providing input through the UI, the value within Ember inspector for `groups` becomes a string and no longer a computed property. How do I avoid this in Ember 2.1 and have it merely update the computed property?

Comment: What yo you mean by _update the computed property_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because the `{{input}}` helper uses two-way binding by default. When you write in the input field it will write to the `value` property.

I've been using [dockyard's one-way-input](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-one-way-input) addon, that provides an input component with one-way binding by default.

```
{{one-way-input
  value=groups
  update=(action 'updateSomething')
}}
```

And then in wherever you're using the component:

```
actions : {
  updateSomething(value) {
    //Do Something with the value and update model.items.groups?
  }
}
```

This way, the value is always read from the `groups` computed property and the action updates the source of the value (and not the computed property)